# Cloud Foundry cf dev start unable to find VM IP address

Tags: ubuntu, cloud-foundry, kvm, cf-bosh, pcfdev

I'm trying to setup a CF Dev environment on a remote virtual server running Ubuntu. After following the documentation on [Github](https://github.com/cloudfoundry-incubator/cfdev) about CF DEV I come about the following issue.

After the 60gb download is completed Cloud Foundry will try to start the Virtual Machine's it created for the environment. But at the step **Fetching VM Address** the setup will exit with the following error:

```
cf dev start: unable to find VM IP address from '/var/lib/libvirt/dnsmasq/virbr0.status'
```

After looking into the contents of the file it mentioned i can clearly see there is an IP-Address *(blurred the real address)*

```
[
  {
    "ip-address": "192.168.***.***",
    "mac-address": "0a:0b:**:**:**:**",
    "hostname": "linuxkit-0a0********",
    "client-id": "01:0a:0b:12:********",
    "expiry-time": 1602239024
  }
]
```

I already set the premissions of the file and it's folder to **775**. So the program should be able to read the file with the IP Address.

Is there a possibility it is not possible to run these CF DEV on a virtual server? When i run `kvm-ok` i will get the following result:

```
INFO: Your CPU does not support KVM extensions
INFO: For more detailed results, you should run this as root
HINT:   sudo /usr/sbin/kvm-ok
```

Any help appreciated

Comment: If virtualization is not enabled, you could see that error. Refer to https://github.com/cloudfoundry-incubator/cfdev/issues/107#issuecomment-508202191. That thread has some other suggestions for troubleshooting as well. Hope that helps!

Comment: I ran into the exact same error while trying to install cf dev on a remote 64bit server. Found this issue: https://github.com/cloudfoundry-attic/cfdev/issues/107. But they didn:t merge the extended timout in their last realease unfortunately.